# ¿Por que el Scanner no lee las variables y a veces manda un exception?

Tags: java, scanner

Tengo el siguiente problema: al correr el programa se muestra el menu con toda sus opciones pero a la hora de escoger las opciones solo agarra la numero 1 y la 5 que son las que piden datos, despues al introducir dichos datos pasan dos cosas:

1. No hace nada al apretar enter y sigue pidiendo infinitamente
2. Manda el exception: `InputMismatchException`.

Podrian decir donde esta el error para no cometerlo en futuros programas me ayudarian bastante

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int opc = 0;
        Altura altura = new Altura();
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner lee = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("                 .::BIENVENIDO AL SISTEMA::.");
        while (10 != (opc)){
            opc = 0;
        System.out.println("introduzca la opcion que desea utlizar:");
        System.out.println("1#para introduzir una altura");
        System.out.println("2# para sacar la altura mas alta introduzida");
        System.out.println("3# para la altura mas baja intoducida");
        System.out.println("4# para sacar le promedio de las alturas");
        System.out.println("5# mostrar la alturas mayores a una indicada por el usuario");
        System.out.println("10# salir del sistema");
        opc = leer.nextInt();
          switch (opc){
            case 1 :altura.insertar_alt();
                    break;
            case 2 :altura.alt_may();
                    break;
            case 3 :altura.alt_men();
                    break;
            case 4 :altura.altura_pro();
                    break;
            case 5 :altura.mostrar_altmay();
                    break;
        }
          /**  if (1 == (opc)) {
                altura.insertar_alt();
            }
            if (2 == (opc)) {
                altura.alt_may();
            }
            if (3 == (opc)) {
                System.out.println("la altura menor es: "+altura.alt_men());
            }
            if (4 == (opc)) {
                System.out.println("el romedio de latura es: "+ altura.altura_pro());
            }
            if (5 == (opc)){
                altura.mostrar_altmay();
            }
        **/}
        System.out.println("                      .::SALIENDO DEL SISTEMA::.");
    }
}
```

> Esta es la clase donde se piden los datos:

```
    public class Altura {
    double arre_altura[] = new double[10];
    Scanner lect = new Scanner(System.in); 

    public void Altura(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arre_altura[i] = 0;
        }
        }

    public int vacio(){ //si retorna 1 es vacio 
      if (arre_altura[0]==0){
          return 1;
          }else{
          return 0;
      }
      }

    public int lleno(){ //si retorna 1 esta lleno
      if (arre_altura[9]!=0){
          return 1;
          }else{
          return 0;
      }
      }
         public int pos_v(){ //metodo que busca la primera poscicion vacia
       int pos;
       pos = -1;
       int i = 0;
       while ((pos == -1) || (i<10)) {
           if (0 == arre_altura[i]){
               pos = i;
           }
       }
        return pos;
         }

     public void insertar_alt(){
       String altura = "0";   
       if (lleno()==1) {
           System.out.println("no se han encontrado mas posiciones para almacenar una altura");
            }else{
                System.out.println("inserte la altura que desea registrar: ");
                try{
                altura = lect.nextLine();
                           }catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
               System.out.println("el error es: "+ e );
           }
                double doble = Double.parseDouble(altura);

                   arre_altura[pos_v()] = doble;
                   }

   }

    public void alt_men(){   //metodo que devuelbe la altura mas baja//
            double alt = arre_altura[0];
            if (vacio()==1){
                System.out.println("el arreglo esta vacio");
            }else{
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          if (alt < arre_altura[i]){
              alt = arre_altura[i];

          }
      }

          System.out.println("la menor altura introduzida es: "+ alt);
            }        
        }
    public void altura_pro(){ //calculo del promedio de altura//
      double total= 0;
      int acum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          if (arre_altura[i] != 0){
          total = total + arre_altura[i];
               acum = acum + 1;
          }
      }

        System.out.println("el promedio de las alturas es: "+ total);
     }
    public void mostrar_alt(){
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          if (arre_altura[i]!=0) {
            System.out.println("La altura en el espacio "+i+" es: "+arre_altura[i]);
          }
      }
     }

    public void mostrar_altmay(){
        double i = 0;
        System.out.println("introduzca la altura que desea verificar: ");
        try{
        i = lect.nextDouble();
        }catch (java.util.InputMismatchException x){ 
            System.out.println("el error es: "+ x );
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (i > arre_altura[j]){ 
                System.out.println("altura:"+ arre_altura[j]);                
            }
        }
        System.out.println("esas son las alturas (en caso de no haber encontrado una altura mayor no se habramotrado nada)");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en este metodo **pos_v** que llamas al leer la altura en el metodo insertar_alt(), ya que se queda en un ciclo infinito, debido a que **declaras la variable pos = -1** al iniciar el método, **luego en el while colocas en la condición pos == -1, y esto nunca va a cambiar repitiendose el ciclo infinitamente**

```
public int pos_v(){ //metodo que busca la primera poscicion vacia
   int pos;
   pos = -1;
   int i = 0;
   while ((pos == -1) || (i<10)) { //Ciclo infinito: variable pos siempre sera igual a -1
       if (0 == arre_altura[i]){
           pos = i;
       }
   }
    return pos;
     }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :D, no me habia dado cuenta que no le habia puesto la sentencia para que incrementara, por eso se creaba ese bucle infinito.

Answer (score 0):

En el case 2 del menú, estas llamando a la funcion alt_may() del objeto altura, pero no la definiste en la clase Altura:

> case 2 :altura.alt_may();
>                       break;

Esa es la causa del error.

**Solución:**
Define la funcion alt_may() en la clase Altura para poder utilizarla.

Comment: esa clase ya esta definida, la cosa es que no la puse en el post (me la salte y ni me fije xD ), pero aun asi el error sigue. Gracias de todos modos :)

Comment: Te aseguraste de importar la clase Scanner? al comienzo del archivo import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: Sep, sino no me dejaria correr el programa por que apareceria ese error en todos los scanner que utilize. pero me parece raro que no los lea